# Does a Windows 7 dvd only have one language?

Tags: windows-7, language

I'm a Dutch developer living in Spain. I recently composed a new computer from new parts and I installed Windows 7 Professional 64 bit (OEM) on it. On the web site of the on-line shop there was a note saying "language: Spanish". Because my English is quite a bit better than my Spanish, but mainly because it is much easier to find information on the web in English, I want my OS to be in English. I asked the on-line shop if they also sold the UK version of Windows 7 but they assured me that "all Windows 7 versions are multi-language". 
With the installation of XP a few years ago, I remember that I was offered the option English or Spanish while the installation process was still in the DOS-like (non-graphical) screen. While installing Windows 7, I did not see any non-graphical screen and the first time I was asked about the language, was in a drop-down list that contained only Spanish.

I know about the language pack possibility of Windows 7, but this is not available on Professional. Even if I had Ultimate, I don't know if it would be possible to install Windows in Spanish, and then add English as a second language from a language pack. I get the impression that English has to be the base-language.
Furthermore, I am a bit sceptical until I'd see it in action. What happens with shortcuts (i.e. Select All: ctrl-a in English / ctrl-e in Spanish, and what about logging messages in Event Viewer, etc)

So can anybody tell me how it works with languages in Windows 7? Have I been misinformed by the computer shop? Could it be that OEM versions of Windows are single language an a full installation is not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I've done is download and burn an ISO file with my windows version, but the one in English. 
http://msft-dnl.digitalrivercontent.net/msvista/pub/X15-65805/X15-65805.iso

I've installed it and everything seems to be fine so far. In case I run into any kind of problem (like activiation) I'll add it to this post.

Comment: Activation was successful.

Answer (score 0):

I had the opposite experience, as a Dutch ex-pat living in the US. I wanted to retain some of my Dutch and thought by installing the Dutch language pack this would help. But I too have Windows 7 64-bit Professional. The solution I followed is outlined in [this thread](http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/112035-solved-change-language-windows-7-home-premium-oem-spanish-english.html), although be aware that it violates the EULA and the best (unless someone knows a better and legal solution) option is to purchase an English language OEM copy.

Comment: The use of Vistalizator as proposed in the website under your link does not seem to work for me. It says "Unable to use this version of Windows 7. This build (7601) is not supported. Make sure you have the latest version of Windows". Does the 1 in 7601 stand for sp1?

Comment: The 1 doesn't necessarily stand for SP1, but yes, 7601 is Windows 7 SP1. I'm glad to see you solved your issue.